# Cómo hacer un histograma con labels en Y y con la frecuencia dentro de las barras?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estoy intentando hacer un **histograma** para una base de datos de más de 56,640 palabras.

Quiero mostrar las 200 o más palabras más frecuentes, sin que éstas se acoplen, es decir, que sean legibles en el eje Y. Además, que la frecuencia de cada palabra esté dentro de las barras correspondiente a cada palabra (aunque esto no es 100% necesario, es simplemente para mejor lectura).

**Mi código:**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter

def histogram(word_list, n):
  n = n # tengo que hacer esto para que el parámetro lo reconozca en .most_common(n).
  counts = dict(Counter(word_list).most_common(n))
  labels, values = zip(*counts.items())

  # ordenar los valores de manera descendiente
  indSort = np.argsort(values)[::-1]

  # reajustar los datos
  labels = np.array(labels)[indSort]
  values = np.array(values)[indSort]

  indexes = np.arange(len(labels))

  # configuración de la figura
  plt.figure(figsize = (15, 4))
  bar_width = 0.35
  plt.bar(indexes, values, color = 'r')

  # agrego las etiquetas
  plt.xticks((indexes + bar_width), labels, rotation = 'vertical')
  plt.tight_layout()
  plt.show()

histogram(word_index, 201)
```

[image: resultado]

**OUTPUT ESPERADO** (imagen otorgada por @FJSevilla):
[image: output]

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: @Bicho no es legible, no están las etiquetas en el eje Y, la frecuencia aparece como un indicador en el eje Y y no dentro de cada barra

Comment: Hola Gunter, 200 palabras  con una fuente de un tamaño medio legible posiblemente no se puedan mostrar en el ancho de la pantalla.... ¿Podrías usar algun framework gráfico paraa añadirle baarraas de scrooll al gráfico? El mismo tkinter podría valer

Comment: @FJSevilla, por supuesto, lo puedo hacer en un rato, de todas maneras aún no se bien como cambiar los labels que los tengo en el X y dejarlos horizontal en el eje Y. Y también la frecuencia dentro de las barras.

Comment: ¿Pero entonces las barras sería horizontales en vez de verticales, con los porcentajes dentro de cada barra y con la palabra en el eje y? Algo parecido a esto: https://s2.qwant.com/thumbr/0x380/6/1/06398bb181b2c57b9ee423c640f768c4c892a554f09de9e8125648acf9de37/128-ggplot-examples-horizontal-bar-plot-1.png?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.datanovia.com%2Fen%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fdn-tutorials%2Fggplot2%2Ffigures%2F128-ggplot-examples-horizontal-bar-plot-1.png&q=0&b=1&p=0&a=1

Comment: @FJSevilla exactamente de esa manera.

Comment: De todos modos, si el problema es que no se puede mostrar bien por el ancho de la pantalla, quizás se pueda hacer por rango. Mostrar palabras más concurridas del 100 al 200 `histogram(100, 200)`

Answer (score 0):

Solución:

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

def histogram(text, N):
  words = text.split()
  counts = Counter(words)
  serie = pd.Series(counts) # convertir el diccionario a pandas Series object

  # ordenar los valores en orden ascendente de las palabras mas frecuentes en N veces
  first_N = serie.sort_values().tail(N)

  ax = first_N.plot.barh(figsize=(8, 16)) # hacer la figura horizontal
  i = 0
  xoffset = 0.1 # ajustar el texto de las etiquetas
  for v in first_N.values:
    # adds the text next to each bar
    ax.text(y=i, x=v + xoffset, s=v, ha='left', va='center') 
    i += 1
```